# Xamarin Maps displays but doesn't update

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm attempting to make a google map using Xamarin forms, the pins displays correctly and zooms in onto the user. It displays the inital map when the page starts, but when moving or zooming the map doesn't change and becomes grids if you zoom in enough. I can see my pin on the grid and everything, but I would like the map to load along with the pin.

```
public partial class IssueMap2 : ContentPage
{
    public UIIssueVM Issue { get; set; }
    public GeoLocation Location { get; set; }

    public bool AllowPinMovment { get; set; }

    private ExtendedMap.ExtendedMap map;
    public Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position OrgIssueLocation { get; set; }
    bool IsGettingLocation = false;




    bool bMapCtrlReady = false;
    IGeolocator Locator;

    public IssueMap2(UIIssueVM Issue, GeoLocation location)
    {
        AllowPinMovment = false;
        this.Issue = Issue;
        this.Location = location;
        Title = "Map";


        OrgIssueLocation = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Issue.Latitude, Issue.Longitude);

        Locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        if (Locator.DesiredAccuracy != 100)
            Locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;


        if (Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.WinPhone)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            map = new ExtendedMap.ExtendedMap()
            {
                IsShowingUser = true,
                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 960,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            map.LongTap += OnMapLongTap;
            map.Ready += MapCtrlReady;
            slMap.Children.Add(map);
        }

    }

    public void MapCtrlReady(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        bMapCtrlReady = true;
    }

    public void OnMapLongTap(object sender, ExtendedMap.TapEventArgs args)
    {
        if (AllowPinMovment == false)
            return;

        if (Issue == null)
            return;

        var pos = args.Position;

        // Update Issue
        Issue.Latitude = pos.Latitude;
        Issue.Longitude = pos.Longitude;
        Issue.Changed = true;

        // Update Pin
        map.Pins.Clear();
        AddPin(pos, Issue.Title, Issue.Description);
    }

    protected void AddPin(Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position pos, String Title, String Desc)
    {
        // MAP pin does not like it if labels are empty
        if (Title.Length == 0)
            Title = "-";

        if (Desc.Length == 0)
            Desc = "-";

        var pin = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = pos,
            Label = Title,
            Address = Desc
        };
        map.Pins.Add(pin);
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.WinPhone)
        {
            aActIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            aActIndicator.IsVisible = false;

            if (Issue.IsNew == false)
            {
                var position = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Issue.Latitude, Issue.Longitude);
                AddPin(position, Issue.Title, Issue.Description);
                MoveToPinLocation();
            }
            else // Issue is new
            {
                // Move to main location
                map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Location.Latitude, Location.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
                // Get current location for new item
                OnGetLocation();

            }
        }
    }


    protected override async void OnDisappearing()
    {
        if (Locator.IsListening)
        {
            await Locator.StopListeningAsync();
        }

        // Map controller crashes sometimes if we are to quick with exiting
        await Task.Delay(500);

        while (bMapCtrlReady == false)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }

    void OnButtonCenter(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MoveToPinLocation();
    }

    void MoveToPinLocation()
    {
        double KmDistace = 0.5;

        if (Issue != null)
        {
            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Issue.Latitude, Issue.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(KmDistace)));
        }
        else
            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Location.Latitude, Location.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(KmDistace)));

    }

    void OnButtonMainLocation(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        double KmDistace = 0.5;
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Location.Latitude, Location.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(KmDistace)));
    }

    void OnButtonGetLocation(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        OnGetLocation();
    }

    async void OnGetLocation()
    {
        if (IsGettingLocation == true)
            return; // already getting location

        try
        {
            if (Locator.IsListening == true)
            {
                await Locator.StopListeningAsync();
            }

            if (Locator.IsGeolocationAvailable == false)
            {
                lbPosText.Text = "GeoLocation is not available.";
                this.ForceLayout();
                return;
            }

            if (Locator.IsGeolocationEnabled == false)
            {
                lbPosText.Text = "GeoLocation is not enabled.";
                this.ForceLayout();
                return;
            }

            IsGettingLocation = true;

            IsBusy = true;
            slCommands.IsVisible = false;
            aActIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            aActIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            lbPosText.Text = "Searching for GPS location...";
            this.ForceLayout();

            TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(120 * 1000);
            var position = await Locator.GetPositionAsync(timeSpan);

            // Update Issue Position
            Issue.Latitude = position.Latitude;
            Issue.Longitude = position.Longitude;
            Issue.Changed = true;


            // Update Pin Postion
            var pos = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Issue.Latitude, Issue.Longitude);
            map.Pins.Clear();
            AddPin(pos, Issue.Title, Issue.Description);

            UpdateGPSLocationText();

            aActIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            aActIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            IsGettingLocation = false;
            IsBusy = false;
            slCommands.IsVisible = true;
            this.ForceLayout();
            // Center map around pin
            MoveToPinLocation();
        }
        catch (Exception /*ex*/)
        {
            aActIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            aActIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            IsGettingLocation = false;
            IsBusy = false;
            slCommands.IsVisible = true;
            lbPosText.Text = "Unable to find position!";
            lbPosText.IsVisible = true;
            this.ForceLayout();
        }
    }

    void UpdateGPSLocationText()
    {
        String text = String.Format("{0} x {1}", Issue.Longitude, Issue.Latitude);
        lbPosText.Text = text;
    }



}
```

}

Android extended map renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedMap.ExtendedMap), typeof(ExtendedMapRenderer))]
namespace ExtendedMap.Android
{
    public class ExtendedMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private GoogleMap _map;

        public ExtendedMapRenderer()
        {
        }

        public ExtendedMapRenderer(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership jniHandleOwnership)
        {

            int x = 0;
            x++;
        }

        private void InvokeOnMapReadyBaseClassHack(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo onMapReadyMethodInfo = null;

            Type baseType = typeof(MapRenderer);
            foreach (var currentMethod in baseType.GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                              System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
            {

                if (currentMethod.IsFinal && currentMethod.IsPrivate)
                {
                    if (string.Equals(currentMethod.Name, "OnMapReady", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        onMapReadyMethodInfo = currentMethod;

                        break;
                    }

                    if (currentMethod.Name.EndsWith(".OnMapReady", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        onMapReadyMethodInfo = currentMethod;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (onMapReadyMethodInfo != null)
            {
                onMapReadyMethodInfo.Invoke(this, new[] { googleMap });
            }
        }


        void IOnMapReadyCallback.OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            InvokeOnMapReadyBaseClassHack(googleMap);
            _map = googleMap;
            if (_map != null)
            {
                _map = googleMap;
                this.NativeMap = googleMap;
                _map.MapClick += googleMap_MapClick;
                _map.MapLongClick += googleMap_MapLongClick;

                ((ExtendedMap)Element).OnReady();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            if (_map != null)
                _map.MapClick -= googleMap_MapClick;
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
                ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }

        private void googleMap_MapClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MapClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ExtendedMap)Element).OnTap(new Position(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude));
        }


        private void googleMap_MapLongClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MapLongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ExtendedMap)Element).OnLongTap(new Position(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check the Google Maps API key on the manifest of your application!

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzr3yCpVgSOXvTgri29nC6KqFbdO73QmoVQWEw" />
```

As well as your SHA-1 key of your keystore on the Google API Credential Dashboard.

Comment: Doubt this is the problem, I double checked and the keys were correct. Earlier Before I had a key, it displayed only blank, now it displays but doesn't load properly. So the key seems fine.

Comment: This is embarassing, but apparently the WIFI was off, Everything works fine.